# PHP Session upload_progress not found in php INI

Tags: php

PHP 5.4 introduce a new feature to track file upload. this feature is

$_SESSION upload_progress.

We have to enable it via php.ini.

Though I can't find any place in my php.ini to enable this option. What's the problem?

My php version is 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these params to your php.ini file.

```
session.upload_progress.enabled = on
session.upload_progress.prefix = "upload_progress_"
session.upload_progress.name = "blabla"
```

Check this `<form>`

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="blabla" />
 <input type="file" name="file1" />
 <input type="file" name="file2" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and on your PHP..

```
<?php
$_SESSION["upload_progress_blabla"] = array(
 "start_time" => 1234567890,   // The request time
 "content_length" => 57343257, // POST content length
 "bytes_processed" => 453489,  // Amount of bytes received and processed
 "done" => false,              // true when the POST handler has finished, successfully or not
 "files" => array(
```

This is a mixture of information and taken from [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) as well. You need to check out that *seriously*.